# Multiple Select validation with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have this multiple select:

```
<select id="sel_dest" name="dest_var[]" multiple disabled="disabled" size="10">
<option value="" selected>Destinatario</option>
<option value="1"> .........
</select>
```

how can i validate (required field) this select with jquery validation plugin?

this code doesn't work:

```
$("#register_form").validate({
rules: {
    dest_var: {
        required: true;
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use a `required` class for the select tag.(and remove the `[]` in the id)

```
<select id="sel_dest" name="dest_var" class="required" multiple disabled="disabled" size="10">
<option value="" selected>Destinatario</option>
<option value="1"> .........
</select>
```

script:

```
$("#register_form").validate();
```

Answer (score 2):

"dest_var[]" : {required: true}

Answer (score 1):

You can see how to do it on the [this example page](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/radio-checkbox-select-demo.html).

```
rules: { 
    dest_var: { 
        required: true,
        rangelength:[2,3]
    }
}
```